# Inserir o género do cliente no banco de dados

Tags: php

Olá pessoal sou novo aqui no forum e gostaria de uma ajuda para colocar para quando o cliente seleccionar um sexo inserir dentro do banco de dados.
Obrigado desde já.

```html
<?php
require_once('includes/Autoloader.php');
$db = new Conn();

$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$usuario = isset($_POST['usuario']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['usuario'])) : false;
$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['nome'])) : false;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['password'])) : false;
$password2 = isset($_POST['password2']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['password2'])) : false;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['email'])) : false;
$errors = array();
$success = false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $db->_open_conn();
 
 if(empty($usuario)){
  $errors[] = 'Por favor coloque um nome de usuário.';
 }else if(strlen($usuario) < 4 || strlen($usuario) > 16){
  $errors[] = 'O nome de usuário deve conter entre 4-16 caracteres.';
 }else if(ctype_alnum($usuario) === false){
  $errors[] = 'O nome de usuário só pode ser letras e números.';
 }else{
  $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT UsuarioID FROM C_Client.dbo.Clientes WHERE UsuarioID=?");
  $stmt->bindValue(1, $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
  if(!$stmt){
   $errors[] = 'Falha ao verificar o nome do usuário.';
  }
  elseif($data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
   $errors[] = 'Este nome de usuário já está em uso. Por favor escolha outro.';
  }
 }
 if(empty($password)){
  $errors[] = 'Por favor insira uma senha';
 }else if(strlen($password) < 6 || strlen($password) > 20){
  $errors[] = 'A senha deve conter entre 6-20 caracteres.';
 }else if($password != $password2){
  $errors[] = 'As senhas não combinam';
 }

    if(empty($email)){
        $errors[] = 'Por favor insira um endereço de E-mail';
    }else if(strlen($email) < 12 || strlen($email) > 64){
        $errors[] = 'O endereço de E-Mail deve conter entre 12-64 caracteres.';
    }else{
        $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT Email FROM C_Client.dbo.Clientes WHERE Email=?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if(!$stmt){
            $errors[] = 'Falha ao verificar o Endereço de E-Mail.';
        }
        elseif($data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
            $errors[] = 'Este endereço de e-mail já está em uso. Por favor utilize outro.';
        }
    }

    if(empty($nome)){
        $errors[] = 'Por favor insira um nome válido.';
    }else if(strlen($nome) < 4 || strlen($nome) > 64){
        $errors[] = 'O nome deve conter entre 4-64 caracteres.';
    }

 if(count($errors) == 0){
  $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO C_Client.dbo.Clientes (UsuarioID, Nome, Password, Email)VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

  $stmt->bindValue(1, $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(4, $user_ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(5, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  if($stmt->execute()){
   $success = "{$nome} sua conta foi criada com sucesso!";
  }else{
   $errors[] = 'Falha ao criar uma conta, por favor tente mais tarde!';
  }
 }
}
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="pt-br">

  <head>
    <title>Country</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" ">
    <meta name="viewport " content="width=device-width, inital-scale1.0 ">
    <link rel="icon " href="img/favicon.png ">
    <!-- MATERIALIZER CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css ">
    <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/custom.css ">
    <!-- DOWN-CONTENT CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/down-content.css ">
    <!-- TOOLTIPSTER CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/tooltipster.bundle.css ">
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/tooltipster-follower.css ">
    <!-- GOOGLE ICONS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons " rel="stylesheet ">
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative:400,700 " rel="stylesheet ">
    <!-- - -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css ">


</head>
<body>

    <div id="top " class="navbar ">
        <?php include "top.php " ?>
    </div>

<div id="main " class="row container banner col s12 center ">
    <div class="logo ">
        <img src="img/favicon.png ">
    </div>

    <div class="panel ">
    <div class="top "></div>
    <div class="body ">
        <div class="title ">Cadastro
            <br>
            <div class="separador ">
                    <img src="img/panel/separador-horizontal.png ">
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Bem Vindo</p>

        <form method="post ">

        <?php if(count($errors)){ ?>
                        <ul id="error ">
                        <?php foreach($errors as $error){ ?>
                            <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php }else{
                        ?><div class="success "><?php echo $success; ?></div><?
                    } ?>


        <div class="input-field ">
            <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca ">person</i>
            <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST[ 'nome'])){ echo $_POST[ 'nome']; } ?>" type="texto" name="nome" id="nome" maxlength="64" placeholder="NOME" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca">person</i>
      <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){ echo $_POST['usuario']; } ?>" type="texto" name="usuario" id="usuario" maxlength="16" placeholder="USÚARIO" required="required" />
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca">lock</i>
      <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST['password'])){ echo $_POST['password']; } ?>" type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="16" placeholder="SENHA" onfocus="removeDisabled()" required="required" pattern="(?=^.{8,16}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"
      />

    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca">repeat</i>
      <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST['password2'])){ echo $_POST['password2']; } ?>" type="password" name="password2" id="password2" maxlength="16" placeholder="REPITA A SENHA" required="required" pattern="(?=^.{8,16}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"
      />

    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca">email</i>
      <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" type="texto" name="email" id="email" maxlength="64" placeholder="E-MAIL" required="required" />

    </div>

    <center>
      <select class="browser-default personalizar-select">
        <option value="">Sexo</option>
        <option value="1">Masculino</option>
        <option value="2">Feminino</option>
        <option value="3">Outro</option>
      </select>
    </center>



    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Limpar" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Criar Conta" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider-footer"></div>

    <footer id="rodape">
      <div class="Pane Pane--dirtLight Pane--bgBottom bordered">
        <div class="Pane-bg">
          <div class="Pane-overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Pane-content">
          <div class="gutter-normal gutter-vertical">
            <div class="SocialLinks SocialLinks--wow">
              <div class="SocialLinks-title FooterText">2019 &copy; Country Todos os Direitos Reservados</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    </div>


    <!-- JQUERY JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MATERIALIZE JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- - -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/iamceege/tooltipster/4.2.5/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- - -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/louisameline/tooltipster-follower/0.1.5/dist/js/tooltipster-follower.min.js"></script>
    <!-- - -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip.js"></script>


    <!-- sidenav -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
        var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
      });
    </script>

    <!-- DOMContent -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
        var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);
      });

      $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
    </script>

    <!-- DropDown -->
    <script>
      $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
        container: document.body
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
        $('.collapsible').collapsible();
        $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
        $('.modal').modal();
      }); // end of document ready
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('form[name=reg_form]').process_reg_form();
      });
    </script>

    <!-- select -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').formSelect();
      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /*  jQuery Nice Select - v1.0
          https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select
          Made by Hernán Sartorio  */
      ! function(e) {
        e.fn.niceSelect = function(t) {
          function s(t) {
            t.after(e("<div></div>").addClass("nice-select").addClass(t.attr("class") || "").addClass(t.attr("disabled") ? "disabled" : "").attr("tabindex", t.attr("disabled") ? null : "0").html('<span class="current"></span><ul class="list"></ul>'));
            var s = t.next(),
              n = t.find("option"),
              i = t.find("option:selected");
            s.find(".current").html(i.data("display") || i.text()), n.each(function(t) {
              var n = e(this),
                i = n.data("display");
              s.find("ul").append(e("<li></li>").attr("data-value", n.val()).attr("data-display", i || null).addClass("option" + (n.is(":selected") ? " selected" : "") + (n.is(":disabled") ? " disabled" : "")).html(n.text()))
            })
          }
          if ("string" == typeof t) return "update" == t ? this.each(function() {
            var t = e(this),
              n = e(this).next(".nice-select"),
              i = n.hasClass("open");
            n.length && (n.remove(), s(t), i && t.next().trigger("click"))
          }) : "destroy" == t ? (this.each(function() {
            var t = e(this),
              s = e(this).next(".nice-select");
            s.length && (s.remove(), t.css("display", ""))
          }), 0 == e(".nice-select").length && e(document).off(".nice_select")) : console.log('Method "' + t + '" does not exist.'), this;
          this.hide(), this.each(function() {
            var t = e(this);
            t.next().hasClass("nice-select") || s(t)
          }), e(document).off(".nice_select"), e(document).on("click.nice_select", ".nice-select", function(t) {
            var s = e(this);
            e(".nice-select").not(s).removeClass("open"), s.toggleClass("open"), s.hasClass("open") ? (s.find(".option"), s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"), s.find(".selected").addClass("focus")) : s.focus()
          }), e(document).on("click.nice_select", function(t) {
            0 === e(t.target).closest(".nice-select").length && e(".nice-select").removeClass("open").find(".option")
          }), e(document).on("click.nice_select", ".nice-select .option:not(.disabled)", function(t) {
            var s = e(this),
              n = s.closest(".nice-select");
            n.find(".selected").removeClass("selected"), s.addClass("selected");
            var i = s.data("display") || s.text();
            n.find(".current").text(i), n.prev("select").val(s.data("value")).trigger("change")
          }), e(document).on("keydown.nice_select", ".nice-select", function(t) {
            var s = e(this),
              n = e(s.find(".focus") || s.find(".list .option.selected"));
            if (32 == t.keyCode || 13 == t.keyCode) return s.hasClass("open") ? n.trigger("click") : s.trigger("click"), !1;
            if (40 == t.keyCode) {
              if (s.hasClass("open")) {
                var i = n.nextAll(".option:not(.disabled)").first();
                i.length > 0 && (s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"), i.addClass("focus"))
              } else s.trigger("click");
              return !1
            }
            if (38 == t.keyCode) {
              if (s.hasClass("open")) {
                var l = n.prevAll(".option:not(.disabled)").first();
                l.length > 0 && (s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"), l.addClass("focus"))
              } else s.trigger("click");
              return !1
            }
            if (27 == t.keyCode) s.hasClass("open") && s.trigger("click");
            else if (9 == t.keyCode && s.hasClass("open")) return !1
          });
          var n = document.createElement("a").style;
          return n.cssText = "pointer-events:auto", "auto" !== n.pointerEvents && e("html").addClass("no-csspointerevents"), this
        }
      }(jQuery);

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.personalizar-select').niceSelect();
      });
    </script>

    </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando voce envia um form usando PHP, os campos do formulario sao enviados atraves do atributo `name`, entao o primeiro passo eh incluir esse atributo no seu codigo HTML, no elemento `select`. Tambem alterei os atributos `value` das suas opcoes. Eh dificil identificar sexos **1, 2 e 3**; faz mais sentido algo do tipo **"M", "F" e "O"**.

O segundo passo, eh "ler" esse campo no seu codigo PHP. Na linha 12, eu inclui uma nova variavel que vai receber o campo **sexo**. Nas linhas 65 a 80, eu alterei o SQL para incluir o campo **Sexo** e inserir a variavel que criamos antes.

O ultimo passo para tudo isso funcionar, eh alterar o seu banco de dados e incluir o campo **Sexo** na tabela de **Clientes**. Se nao fizer isso, a informacao nao era salva.

Aqui esta o codigo ajustado:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/Autoloader.php');
$db = new Conn();

$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$usuario = isset($_POST['usuario']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['usuario'])) : false;
$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['nome'])) : false;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['password'])) : false;
$password2 = isset($_POST['password2']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['password2'])) : false;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['email'])) : false;
$sexo = isset($_POST['sexo']) ? $db->mssql_escape_string(trim($_POST['sexo'])) : false;
$errors = array();
$success = false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $db->_open_conn();

    if(empty($usuario)){
        $errors[] = 'Por favor coloque um nome de usuário.';
    }else if(strlen($usuario) < 4 || strlen($usuario) > 16){
        $errors[] = 'O nome de usuário deve conter entre 4-16 caracteres.';
    }else if(ctype_alnum($usuario) === false){
        $errors[] = 'O nome de usuário só pode ser letras e números.';
    }else{
        $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT UsuarioID FROM C_Client.dbo.Clientes WHERE UsuarioID=?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if(!$stmt){
            $errors[] = 'Falha ao verificar o nome do usuário.';
        }
        elseif($data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
            $errors[] = 'Este nome de usuário já está em uso. Por favor escolha outro.';
        }
    }
    if(empty($password)){
        $errors[] = 'Por favor insira uma senha';
    }else if(strlen($password) < 6 || strlen($password) > 20){
        $errors[] = 'A senha deve conter entre 6-20 caracteres.';
    }else if($password != $password2){
        $errors[] = 'As senhas não combinam';
    }

    if(empty($email)){
        $errors[] = 'Por favor insira um endereço de E-mail';
    }else if(strlen($email) < 12 || strlen($email) > 64){
        $errors[] = 'O endereço de E-Mail deve conter entre 12-64 caracteres.';
    }else{
        $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT Email FROM C_Client.dbo.Clientes WHERE Email=?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if(!$stmt){
            $errors[] = 'Falha ao verificar o Endereço de E-Mail.';
        }
        elseif($data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
            $errors[] = 'Este endereço de e-mail já está em uso. Por favor utilize outro.';
        }
    }

    if(empty($nome)){
        $errors[] = 'Por favor insira um nome válido.';
    }else if(strlen($nome) < 4 || strlen($nome) > 64){
        $errors[] = 'O nome deve conter entre 4-64 caracteres.';
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $stmt   =   $db->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO C_Client.dbo.Clientes (UsuarioID, Nome, Password, Email, Sexo)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(4, $user_ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(5, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(6, $sexo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $success = "{$nome} sua conta foi criada com sucesso!";
        }else{
            $errors[] = 'Falha ao criar uma conta, por favor tente mais tarde!';
        }
    }
}
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="pt-br">

  <head>
    <title>Country</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" ">
    <meta name="viewport " content="width=device-width, inital-scale1.0 ">
    <link rel="icon " href="img/favicon.png ">
    <!-- MATERIALIZER CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css ">
    <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/custom.css ">
    <!-- DOWN-CONTENT CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/down-content.css ">
    <!-- TOOLTIPSTER CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/tooltipster.bundle.css ">
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/tooltipster-follower.css ">
    <!-- GOOGLE ICONS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons " rel="stylesheet ">
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative:400,700 " rel="stylesheet ">
    <!-- - -->
    <link rel="stylesheet " href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css ">


</head>
<body>

    <div id="top " class="navbar ">
        <?php include "top.php " ?>
    </div>

<div id="main " class="row container banner col s12 center ">
    <div class="logo ">
        <img src="img/favicon.png ">
    </div>

    <div class="panel ">
    <div class="top "></div>
    <div class="body ">
        <div class="title ">Cadastro
            <br>
            <div class="separador ">
                    <img src="img/panel/separador-horizontal.png ">
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Bem Vindo</p>

        <form method="post ">

        <?php if(count($errors)){ ?>
                        <ul id="error ">
                        <?php foreach($errors as $error){ ?>
                            <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php }else{
                        ?><div class="success "><?php echo $success; ?></div><?
                    } ?>


        <div class="input-field ">
            <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca ">person</i>
            <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST[ 'nome'])){ echo $_POST[ 'nome']; } ?>" type="texto" name="nome" id="nome" maxlength="64" placeholder="NOME" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca">person</i>
      <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){ echo $_POST['usuario']; } ?>" type="texto" name="usuario" id="usuario" maxlength="16" placeholder="USÚARIO" required="required" />
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca">lock</i>
      <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST['password'])){ echo $_POST['password']; } ?>" type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="16" placeholder="SENHA" onfocus="removeDisabled()" required="required" pattern="(?=^.{8,16}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"
      />

    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca">repeat</i>
      <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST['password2'])){ echo $_POST['password2']; } ?>" type="password" name="password2" id="password2" maxlength="16" placeholder="REPITA A SENHA" required="required" pattern="(?=^.{8,16}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"
      />

    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="material-icons prefix icon-color-ca">email</i>
      <input value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" type="texto" name="email" id="email" maxlength="64" placeholder="E-MAIL" required="required" />

    </div>

    <center>
      <select class="browser-default personalizar-select" name="sexo" id="sexo">
        <option value="">Sexo</option>
        <option value="M">Masculino</option>
        <option value="F">Feminino</option>
        <option value="O">Outro</option>
      </select>
    </center>



    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Limpar" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Criar Conta" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider-footer"></div>

    <footer id="rodape">
      <div class="Pane Pane--dirtLight Pane--bgBottom bordered">
        <div class="Pane-bg">
          <div class="Pane-overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Pane-content">
          <div class="gutter-normal gutter-vertical">
            <div class="SocialLinks SocialLinks--wow">
              <div class="SocialLinks-title FooterText">2019 &copy; Country Todos os Direitos Reservados</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    </div>


    <!-- JQUERY JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MATERIALIZE JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- - -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/iamceege/tooltipster/4.2.5/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- - -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/louisameline/tooltipster-follower/0.1.5/dist/js/tooltipster-follower.min.js"></script>
    <!-- - -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip.js"></script>


    <!-- sidenav -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
        var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
      });
    </script>

    <!-- DOMContent -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
        var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);
      });

      $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
    </script>

    <!-- DropDown -->
    <script>
      $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
        container: document.body
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
        $('.collapsible').collapsible();
        $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
        $('.modal').modal();
      }); // end of document ready
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('form[name=reg_form]').process_reg_form();
      });
    </script>

    <!-- select -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').formSelect();
      });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /*  jQuery Nice Select - v1.0
          https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select
          Made by Hernán Sartorio  */
      ! function(e) {
        e.fn.niceSelect = function(t) {
          function s(t) {
            t.after(e("<div></div>").addClass("nice-select").addClass(t.attr("class") || "").addClass(t.attr("disabled") ? "disabled" : "").attr("tabindex", t.attr("disabled") ? null : "0").html('<span class="current"></span><ul class="list"></ul>'));
            var s = t.next(),
              n = t.find("option"),
              i = t.find("option:selected");
            s.find(".current").html(i.data("display") || i.text()), n.each(function(t) {
              var n = e(this),
                i = n.data("display");
              s.find("ul").append(e("<li></li>").attr("data-value", n.val()).attr("data-display", i || null).addClass("option" + (n.is(":selected") ? " selected" : "") + (n.is(":disabled") ? " disabled" : "")).html(n.text()))
            })
          }
          if ("string" == typeof t) return "update" == t ? this.each(function() {
            var t = e(this),
              n = e(this).next(".nice-select"),
              i = n.hasClass("open");
            n.length && (n.remove(), s(t), i && t.next().trigger("click"))
          }) : "destroy" == t ? (this.each(function() {
            var t = e(this),
              s = e(this).next(".nice-select");
            s.length && (s.remove(), t.css("display", ""))
          }), 0 == e(".nice-select").length && e(document).off(".nice_select")) : console.log('Method "' + t + '" does not exist.'), this;
          this.hide(), this.each(function() {
            var t = e(this);
            t.next().hasClass("nice-select") || s(t)
          }), e(document).off(".nice_select"), e(document).on("click.nice_select", ".nice-select", function(t) {
            var s = e(this);
            e(".nice-select").not(s).removeClass("open"), s.toggleClass("open"), s.hasClass("open") ? (s.find(".option"), s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"), s.find(".selected").addClass("focus")) : s.focus()
          }), e(document).on("click.nice_select", function(t) {
            0 === e(t.target).closest(".nice-select").length && e(".nice-select").removeClass("open").find(".option")
          }), e(document).on("click.nice_select", ".nice-select .option:not(.disabled)", function(t) {
            var s = e(this),
              n = s.closest(".nice-select");
            n.find(".selected").removeClass("selected"), s.addClass("selected");
            var i = s.data("display") || s.text();
            n.find(".current").text(i), n.prev("select").val(s.data("value")).trigger("change")
          }), e(document).on("keydown.nice_select", ".nice-select", function(t) {
            var s = e(this),
              n = e(s.find(".focus") || s.find(".list .option.selected"));
            if (32 == t.keyCode || 13 == t.keyCode) return s.hasClass("open") ? n.trigger("click") : s.trigger("click"), !1;
            if (40 == t.keyCode) {
              if (s.hasClass("open")) {
                var i = n.nextAll(".option:not(.disabled)").first();
                i.length > 0 && (s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"), i.addClass("focus"))
              } else s.trigger("click");
              return !1
            }
            if (38 == t.keyCode) {
              if (s.hasClass("open")) {
                var l = n.prevAll(".option:not(.disabled)").first();
                l.length > 0 && (s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"), l.addClass("focus"))
              } else s.trigger("click");
              return !1
            }
            if (27 == t.keyCode) s.hasClass("open") && s.trigger("click");
            else if (9 == t.keyCode && s.hasClass("open")) return !1
          });
          var n = document.createElement("a").style;
          return n.cssText = "pointer-events:auto", "auto" !== n.pointerEvents && e("html").addClass("no-csspointerevents"), this
        }
      }(jQuery);

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.personalizar-select').niceSelect();
      });
    </script>

    </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Por nada! Boa sorte com o projeto :)